# jQuery script for new list item form only works in edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-editor-web-part

Newbie question. With Sharepoint Online, on a new List I'm modifying the Default New Form and I've added a Content Editor web part. I've linked the Content Editor to a script file that I've uploaded to the Site Assets folder. The script simply loads jQuery (also uploaded to the Site Assets folder), and logs a message to the console.

The script loads and works fine in the Design (Edit) Mode of the form, but in the actual input mode of the form, the script isn't loaded at all.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        console.log("script loaded");     
    }    
</script>
```

Any ideas? Seems like I'm missing something basic.

I also checked [this Q&A](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123407/jquery-accordion-on-wiki-page-only-works-in-edit-mode) and made sure to include the `language` and `type` params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was in fact missing `type="text/javascript"` and works now.

Comment: Now mark your it as your own Answer.. so it is no longer listed as question. tnx