# Why does my Content Editor WebPart (CEWP) work in a page in Edit mode, but not in published mode?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, html, content-editor-web-part

I recently added a Content Editor Webpart with code for an accordion. When I'm using it in on the page in edit mode, there are no issues. For reference, the end of the URL looks like this: /sites/JI/SitePages/Home.aspx

But when I go to the published page (URL like this: /sites/JI/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx), the accordion no longer works. The color still changes when I hover over sections, but clicking has no effect.

Here's a stripped copy of the HTML:

```
<style>
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>

<h2>Header</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
<button class="accordion" type="button">JI Purchasing Instructions</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p><a href="linkhere">link name</a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" type="button">Button Name</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p> <ul>
   <li><a href="link"> linkname</a></li>
   <li><a href="link"> Link Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="link"> Linkname</a></li>
</ul> </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" type="button">Buttonname</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    <ul> 
    <li><a href="Link"> Linkname</a></li>
    <li>Link to <a href="link"> linkname</a>
  </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" type="button">button name</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p> <ul>
    <li><a href="link"> Link Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="link"> Link Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="link"> Link name</a></li>
</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: By "HTML WebPart", I assume you are using the "Content Editor WebPart"?   Also, which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint 2016. By "HTML WebPart", I do mean the Content Editor WebPart. I'm putting in the HTML with the Form Content Editor.

Comment: can you post your html content, kind of hard to troubleshoot or debug without a copy

Comment: I edited it into the main post.

Comment: Related? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/123536/8992

Comment: I saw that post as well, but I'm not using jquery at all, so I'm not sure it's my issue.

Comment: The answer there is not really related to it being jQuery, it's about how the browser is interpreting the `<script>` tags and whether or not they were considered valid or legal without the `language` and `type` attributes.  See the comment below the answer.

Comment: Also it might have to do with MDS being enabled.  Can you disable MDS and check to see if it works then?

Comment: Yes! That was it. When I disabled MDS, it works great. I'll put that in as the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did look at that post, but my issue was due to having MDS enabled. I haven't used jQuery at all in this process.

Comment: I did look at that post, but my issue was due to having MDS enabled. I haven't used jQuery at all in this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dylan Cristy mentioned in the comments, the issue ended up being MDS (Minimal Download Strategy). As soon as I disabled that, the accordion started working.

Answer (score 0):

The html and script that you put in a Content Editor Web Part is being embedded on a containing page, and thus your content should not include a `<DocType>`, `<Body>`, or `<Head>` elements.  Try using the following:

```
<style>
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>

<h2>Header</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
<button class="accordion" type="button">JI Purchasing Instructions</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p><a href="linkhere">link name</a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" type="button">Button Name</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p> <ul>
   <li><a href="link"> linkname</a></li>
   <li><a href="link"> Link Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="link"> Linkname</a></li>
</ul> </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" type="button">Buttonname</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    <ul> 
    <li><a href="Link"> Linkname</a></li>
    <li>Link to <a href="link"> linkname</a>
  </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" type="button">button name</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p> <ul>
    <li><a href="link"> Link Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="link"> Link Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="link"> Link name</a></li>
</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference. It works just fine on the SitePages url, but not with the _layouts url.